# When i run commande composer require laravel/ui="1.*" --dev these error appears .I'm using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/ui[v1.0.0, ..., v1.3.0] require illuminate/console ~5.8|^6.0 -> found illuminate/console[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.24] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui 1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v1.0.0, ..., v1.3.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: did you try to change console ~5.8 into 5.4 and then composer update? then laravel ui

Comment: I fix that when i create new project with the desired laravel version and i placed my files from the old project.